# Django Fecha en Español

Tags: datetime, django-forms

Hola tengo este form y la fecha me la escribe en ingles (Wed Jan 16 17:30) hay alguna manera de que lo haga en español. Por ejemplo Miércoles 16 de Enero 17:30

```
from django import forms
from turnos.models import Turno

class TurnoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Turno
        fields = [
            'fecha',                    
        ]
        labels = {          
            'fecha': 'Fecha: ',     

        }


        widgets = {
                'fecha': forms.DateTimeInput(format="%a %b %d %H:%M",attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}),
            }
```

Comment: Hola,  ¿has editado tu settings.py? para la configuración de lenguaje y zona horaria?

Answer (score 1):

Dentro del archivo settings.py se puede cambiar el idioma y la zona horaria para que las fechas puedan ser obtenidas con un formato diferente al que viene por defecto.

Cada vez que se crea un nuevo proyecto en Django, se crea a su vez un archivo llamado `settings.py`, tal que así:

```
djangoproject
├───manage.py
├───mysite
│        settings.py <--
│        urls.py
│        wsgi.py
│        __init__.py
└───requirements.txt
```

El cual almacena toda la información relevante con respecto a tu proyecto: motor de base de datos a usar, apps que existen dentro del proyecto, información con respecto a los archivos estáticos que posee tu proyecto, etc.

Pero una de las cosas más importantes que te ofrece al final del archivo lo siguiente (por defecto viene de la siguiente manera):

```
    # Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

Donde:

`TIME_ZONE` : modifica la zona horaria

`LANGUAGE_CODE` : para modificar el idioma a usar

En mi caso me encuentro en América, Chile, por lo mismo mi configuración sería la siguiente:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Santiago'
```

Comment: Soy de buenos aires, le puse tu misma configuración pero sale así el campo fecha : Fecha: Wednesday January 16 17:30:

Answer (score 1):

como dijo Riaven hay que cambiar la configuración de settings.py. Soy de Buenos Aires también y lo configuré así:

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-ar'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0):

en al archivo **settings.py**

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
```

Al final búscas estás líneas parecidas y acomodas estas variables del siguiente modo, teniendo en cuenta **LANGUAGE_CODE** que lo puse para colombia

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-co'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

**Ya con esto en donde sea que llames una fecha , aparecerá en español**